# How do I remove the space between the images?

Tags: html, css

[image]
There's a white space by the side and at the top of the images. How to fix this?

Comment: Can you provide some code for us to figure out what's wrong in it?

Comment: Yeah if you show your code then we will be able to figure out what is wrong. And please also comment if my solution was useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should adjust the image position by using CSS. Try adding the below code in your CSS class that defines the style of your image.

```
margin-top: -10px;    
margin-left: -10px;
```

And if this is not sufficient try increasing the magnitude or quantity by increasing the number of the negative pixels. Like try increasing it from **-10px** to **-15px** or **-20px** or so on...

> And while trying this if you get a space in your right side of the image then increase the width of the image to adjust and fit it correctly. Another important thing is don't forget to add the minus on front of the number of pixels.

Comment: Thank you @Vishnu, This resolved the problem; I used a margin-top: - 24px, and marging-left: - 24px.